# Trying to offset columns and add data into predefined number of columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have data being copied into a worksheet from being stored as a variant. I need to offset the data by 2 columns (to the right) and be able to add in the date in the first column and a pre-defined number, stored as a string, into the next column.

Although I can offset the main chunk of data, I cannot work out how to add in the required information into all of the offset cells. I managed to get it to copy to the first row of the data and I have the number of rows of `v` stored as a value (`RowCounter`) if this helps. Just to add background information, this is a cumulative worksheet so data will be constantly added.

The current section of code:

```
  With SupSheet
      .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = Date
      .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(, 1).Value = SupCount
      .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(, 2).Resize(UBound(v, 1), UBound(v, 2)).Value = v
  End With
```

Comment: Could you count the cells in column c after `.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 2).Resize(UBound(v, 1), UBound(v, 2)).Value = v`

Comment: Yes, but I already have this figure (the number of rows as the size of `v`) stored as a variable `RowCounter` from previously in my code.

Comment: I need to get column A xlup + 1 : column A + `RowCounter` = Date and column B xlup + 1 : column B + `RowCounter` = `SupCount`, but I cannot figure out how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the required cells in the specific columns to fill in with a small simple loop that adds data between the `LastRow + 1` and `LastRow + RowCounter`. Below is my entire code. The section this thread was concerned with was between`'Copy to relevant matching sheet` to `'Remove copied rows`

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CreateRETfile()
   Dim rawDataSheet, SupSheet As Worksheet
   Dim newBook As Workbook
   Dim v As Variant
   Dim cc As Variant
   Dim supID, SupCount, NamePrefix As String
   Dim footerCount, Rowcounter, i, j, k As Integer
   Dim lastrow As Long

'Store Supplier ID
Set rawDataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data")
supID = Trim(rawDataSheet.Range("A2").Value)

'Check for records
If IsEmpty(rawDataSheet.Cells(2, 2)) Then
MsgBox ("Error!" & vbNewLine & _
"No records found to create RET file." _
& vbNewLine & "Please add at least 1 record.")
Exit Sub
End If

 'Check for SupID as sheet and if it doesn't exist create it
On Error Resume Next
Set SupSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(supID)
lastrow = SupSheet.Cells(SupSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
On Error GoTo 0
If SupSheet Is Nothing Then
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Set SupSheet = .Add(After:=.Item(.Count))
    End With
    SupSheet.Name = supID
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(supID)
        .Range("A1").Resize(, 17) = Array( _
        "RET", "Init Supplier", "Init Agent", "Unique ID", "MPRN", _
        "House Name/Number", "Street", "Postcode", "Cust Name", "Cust Tele", _
        "No Contact", "CoS Date", "CC Date", "Reason", "Status", "Asso Supplier", "Asso Agent")
        .Range("BA1").NumberFormat = "00000"
        .Range("BA1").Value2 = "10000"
    End With
End If

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(supID).Range("BA1").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(supID).Range("BA1").Value + 1
SupCount = Trim(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(supID).Range("BA1").Text)
NamePrefix = "CTO" & supID & SupCount

'Count Rows to be Copied
cc = rawDataSheet.Range("A2:A10").Value
For j = 1 To UBound(cc, 1)
    If cc(j, 1) = Range("A2") Then Rowcounter = Rowcounter + 1
Next

'Create workbook
Set newBook = Workbooks.Add

'Copy Records
v = rawDataSheet.Range("B2:X" & Rowcounter + 1).Value
For i = 1 To UBound(v, 1)
    If v(i, 1) = "RET" Then footerCount = footerCount + 1
Next

'Write new sheet
With newBook.Worksheets(1)
    'Values
    .Range("A2").Resize(UBound(v, 1), UBound(v, 2)).Value = v
    'Header
    .Range("A1").Resize(, 13) = Array( _
        "ZHF", "CTO", "RET", supID, "RET", "RET", "6", "PROD", _
        NamePrefix & "RET.CSV", NamePrefix, _
        Format(Date, "ddmmyyyy"), "Unknown", "1")
    'Footer
    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(, 3).Value = Array( _
        "ZFV", "BATCH" & SupCount, footerCount)
    'Name
    .Name = NamePrefix & "RET"

    'Save
    .SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & NamePrefix & "RET.CSV"
End With
newBook.Close savechanges:=False

'Copy to relevant matching sheet
With SupSheet
    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 2).Resize(UBound(v, 1), UBound(v, 2)).Value = v
End With

'Fill in date and ID column
For k = lastrow To lastrow + Rowcounter
    If SupSheet.Cells(k, 3).Value = "RET" Then SupSheet.Cells(k, 1).Value = Date
    If SupSheet.Cells(k, 3).Value = "RET" Then SupSheet.Cells(k, 2).Value = SupCount
Next

'Remove copied rows
rawDataSheet.Range("B2:X" & Rowcounter + 1).EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```